# Recover wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, recover

Is it possible to recover your site after an accidentally removed files?

1. Only directories like wp-config,wp-admin,wp-content are left.
2. nothing is left in the parent directory
3. Maybe it is enough just to restore a wp-config.php file to start your web again?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have wp-config, wp-content and wp-admin you should be fine to download [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/), remove those files from the download and copy them over. See here for more detailed info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_-_Extended_Instructions).